# Calculus - improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have a few questions from my h.w, I hope someone can help me.

the question is:

$f:[a,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and periodic function, with period of $T>0$ .

$g:[a,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a monotonic function and $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x) = 0$

Assume that $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = 0$, and that $g$ is differentiable and its derivative is continuous. Prove that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) dx$ converges.

I hope the question is clear. Thank you

Comment: There're directions in the FAQ section how to properly write mathematics in this site with LaTeX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** (many details need to be added)
$$
F(x)=\int_a^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Show that $F$ is periodic with period $T$. Furthermore, since $g$ is monotonic,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^\infty|g'(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\left|\int_a^\infty g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\[6pt]
&=|g(a)|\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm{d}F(x)\\
&=g(b)F(b)-g(a)F(a)-\int_a^bF(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=g(b)F(b)-\int_a^b F(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Show that $(3)$ has a limit as $b\to\infty$.

Comment: I think there is a problem. Did you use $\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x)=0$ in your proof? This condition is not given.

Comment: @xpaul: nope. But we do know that $\int_a^\infty|g'(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x=|g(a)|$ and $F(x)$ is bounded.